# Convert date time format and select distinct in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to select the distinct date time from 2 columns.
First convert the date time into new format 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss' and select only the distinct value. Such as: convert and take the only 1 time value 12:59:43 among 3 results.
But when i try to add format or convert function into this, it was failed or not showing right results. Any help please? Thank you.

The original code i use below:

```sql
SELECT  DISTINCT *
FROM 
( SELECT TOP 100000000
[Start] AS Station_Start_Date,
[End] AS Station_End_Date

FROM ***
WHERE *** = 1476541 AND [End] IS NOT NULL AND [Start] IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY 
[End],
[Start]
ORDER BY [Start] DESC)
```

[image]

Comment: Start by learning proper `GROUP BY`.  What's the point of `GROUP BY` without any aggregation?

Answer (score 1):

try the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT convert(varchar(19), t.Station_Start_Date, 120) Station_Start_Date
, convert(varchar(19), t.Station_End_Date, 120) Station_End_Date
FROM @t t
```

or

```
SELECT convert(varchar(19), t.Station_Start_Date, 120) Station_Start_Date
, convert(varchar(19), t.Station_End_Date, 120) Station_End_Date
FROM @t t
GROUP BY convert(varchar(19), t.Station_Start_Date, 120), convert(varchar(19), t.Station_End_Date, 120)
```

Please find the db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=21b03ec49109d9bc5fea95d22e26cdf2).